# What is the best project structure to use when developing for airflow?

Tags: python, pycharm, airflow

I'm currently developing DAGs for Airflow. I like to use *PyCharm* and tend to spin up a virtual environment for each of my projects.

Airflow depends on an AIRFLOW_HOME folder that gets set during the installation. Subdirectories are then created within this folder by Airflow.

I'm interested in how others structure their projects to allow for virtual environments that contain packages (such as `facebookads`) that are needed for acquiring data - while also easily dropping the DAGs into Airflow's DAGS folder for testing.

Comment: funny coincidence, i am also writing a DAG to access facebook ads :) i'll try to post here my project structure when i solve import issues similar to what Adam is talking in his comment to one of the answers

Answer (score 4):

In our current case, we follow a simple structure:

```
 - dags
  - dag001.py
  - dag001.py
  - helpers
     - dag_001_helpers
         - file01.py
         - file02.py
     - dag_002_helpers
         - file01.py
         - file02.py
   - configs 
     - dag_001_configs
         - file11.json
         - file12.sql
     - dag_002_configs
         - file21.json
         - file22.py
```

Comment: I have taken this approach. It is working well thank you.

Comment: What are the helpers here? Are they custom PythonOperators?

Comment: It is the callable function in the PythonOperator as an example, or the queries for BigQuery operators.

Comment: @Soliman, so where do you define the operators then?

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I use:

```
- config
  - config_1.yaml
  - config_1.env
- DAGs
  - dag_1.py
     -dag_1_etl_1.sql
     -dag_1_etl_2.sql
     -dag_1_etl_3.sql
     -dag_1_bash_1.sh
  - dag_2.py
  - dag_3.py
- operators
  - operator_1.py
  - operator_2.py
  - operator_3.py
- hooks
  - hooks_1.py
```

For our use case: 
1) Every object that can be reused we store in a separate folder with the same *kind of* object;

2) Every DAG in terms of SQL must be self-contained to avoid non-mapped dependencies

Comment: using this structure I get error trying to import the operator into my dag `from operators.[filename] import [module]` module not found.

Comment: here link to my code repo https://github.com/adamdharris/docker-airflow

Comment: @Adam , do you have __init__.py files in each folder?  Not sure it will be enough, i've just started working with Airflow projects, but usually having __init__.py helps treating project as package with subpackages.

Comment: This is a clean approach but unfortunately you cannot use git-sync in Airflow to sync operators and hooks defined outside the 'dags' folder.